# Class functions in an Object (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, class, object

Hi I want to optimize my code so I don't have a lot of if statements.
I've been trying to optimize this code witch is inside a Class

```js
        if (spot.charAt(1) === "P") this.#getMovesPawn(row, col, validMoves);
        if (spot.charAt(1) === "N") this.#getMovesKnight(row, col, validMoves);
        if (spot.charAt(1) === "B") this.#getMovesBishoop(row, col, validMoves);
        if (spot.charAt(1) === "R") this.#getMovesRook(row, col, validMoves);
        if (spot.charAt(1) === "Q") this.#getMovesQueen(row, col, validMoves);
```

First i tried to try putting all of the functions inside an Object

```js
this.moveFunctions = {"P": this.#getMovesBishoop, "B": this.#getMovesBishoop, "N": this.#getMovesKnight,"Q":this.#getMovesQueen, "R": this.#getMovesRook}
// then executing them
this.moveFunctions["P"](0, 0, []);
```

but when doing so the `this` variable changes from the Class variable where all the info is at to just include the functions

```js
// from this
{
    "apple": 1,
    "pear": 2
    ...
}

// to
{"P": this.#getMovesBishoop, "B": this.#getMovesBishoop, "N": this.#getMovesKnight,"Q":this.#getMovesQueen, "R": this.#getMovesRook}
```

my question is how do i manage to make `this.moveFunctions` work or something better? I have searched stackoverflow and google, but nothing i've also tried trying this in python and it worked

Comment: You could use a switch statement in the top part. To call your code from a different context use `call` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to bind the correct `this` - see [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

When you write `a.b()` this is different from `const x = a.b; x()` because the syntax of `a.b()` automatically passes `a` as `this` to the method `a.b`. This automatic "connection" is lost when you do `x()` because it happens only when you do a function call immediately preceded by a property access, but here the property access and the function call happen in two different places.

The behavior you observe is because here there *is* an automatic "connection" to an object but it's not the object you expected, because `["P"]` is a property access as well (just like `.P`) so now you have another `a.b()` situation but with `a` being `this.moveFunctions`!

The solution to both scenarios (no property access before the call at all or property access on an unwanted object) is to either [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the correct `this` to the function (`const x = a.b.bind(a); x()` works) or use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to pass it (`const x = a.b; x.call(a)` works too).

In your case, `call` is probably the easier way:

```js
this.moveFunctions["P"].call(this, 0, 0, []);
```

Comment: Thank you! It took me some time to know how .call() works